# Springboot - Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, intellij-idea, applicationcontext

I have just created the spring boot application from spring initializer and execute it in intellij.But I am facing some error. Can anyone please help me to solve the error?

```
package com.demo.grocery;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class GroceryApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GroceryApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

And this is the error I am facing

```
.   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.2)

2022-07-29 22:12:46.331  INFO 14136 --- [           main] com.demo.grocery.GroceryApplication      : Starting GroceryApplication using Java 11.0.13 on DESKTOP-MQ2O3FR with PID 14136 (C:\Users\keerthi\Downloads\grocery\target\classes started by keerthi in C:\Users\keerthi\Downloads\grocery)
2022-07-29 22:12:46.336  INFO 14136 --- [           main] com.demo.grocery.GroceryApplication      : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-07-29 22:12:47.288  INFO 14136 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-07-29 22:12:47.306  INFO 14136 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 7 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-07-29 22:12:48.437  INFO 14136 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-07-29 22:12:48.463  INFO 14136 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-07-29 22:12:48.463  INFO 14136 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.65]
2022-07-29 22:12:48.721  INFO 14136 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-07-29 22:12:48.721  INFO 14136 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2267 ms
2022-07-29 22:12:48.832  WARN 14136 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
2022-07-29 22:12:48.839  INFO 14136 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-07-29 22:12:48.868  INFO 14136 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-07-29 22:12:48.897 ERROR 14136 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have tried most of the solutions from stackoverflow, help me to solve this error

Comment: How did you configure the database? Please share the complete project: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have not done anything in the project ,just tried to execute the created spring boot project from spring initializer.

Comment: Depending on the options chosen you may actually need to configure it. Refer to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/db_example
spring.datasource.username=springuser
spring.datasource.password=ThePassword
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
#spring.jpa.show-sql: true
```

Paste this in your application properties file in the resource folder.
Change the database name in the second line and also change the username and password according to your database.